# Appending "%" string to the values in HTML Body - Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I have created a script to pull the resource usage for memory and cpu, and highlight the values with high cpu and memory with threshold more than 75%. However, I am unable to append with "%" string after values embedded inside the HTML body

[before string "%"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dld9A.png)

I have tried different ways in the my code below changing the forloop condition from int to string below to highlight the values with more than 75% threshold and append with "%" string. But changing to string type in the HTML body doesn't highlight the correct values i.e., also highlighting values below 75%. Below is the snippet of the code.

[after string "%" added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyNtC.png)

```
    $cpu_total = 0.0
    $mem_total = 0.0
    $thresholdPercent = "75.00%"

    $header = "<style>BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}"
    $header = $header + "TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}"
    $header = $header + "TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }"
    $header = $header + "TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }"
    $header = $header + ".critical{background-color:yellow}"
    $header = $header + ".normal{background-color:white}"
    $header = $header + "</style>"

    foreach ($cpuData in $CPUMetricData.Data.Average) {
        $cpu_total += $cpuData / 14
    }
    foreach ($memData in $memMetricData.Data.Average) {
        $mem_total += $memData / 14
        $totalMemInGB = [math]::floor($virtualMachineMem / 1000)
        $availableMemInGB = [math]::round($mem_total / 1000 / 1000 / 1000, 2)
        $memUsagePercent = [math]::round(($totalMemInGB - $availableMemInGB) / $totalMemInGB * 100, 2)
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        vmName             = $virtualMachineName
        resourceGroupName  = $resourceGroupName
        vmSize             = $virtualMachineSize
        PrivateIP          = $privateIpAddress
        CpuCores           = $virtualMachineCpu
        MemoryInGB         = [string]::Concat($totalMemInGB, "GB")
        CpuUsagePercent    = [string]::Concat([math]::round($cpu_total, 2), "%")
        # MemoryUsagePercent = $memUsagePercent
        MemoryUsagePercent = [string]::Concat($memUsagePercent, "%")
    }
}


[xml]$HTMLBody = $VMResourceInfo `
| Select-Object vmName, resourceGroupName, vmSize, PrivateIP, CpuCores, MemoryInGB, CpuUsagePercent, MemoryUsagePercent `
| ConvertTo-Html -Fragment `

for ($i = 1; $i -le $HTMLBody.table.tr.count - 1; $i++) {
    if (($HTMLBody.table.tr[$i].td[-1] -as [string]) -gt $thresholdPercent) {
        $HTMLBody.table.tr[$i].ChildNodes[($HTMLBody.table.tr[$i].ChildNodes.Count - 1)].SetAttribute('class', 'critical')
    }
    else {
        $HTMLBody.table.tr[$i].ChildNodes[($HTMLBody.table.tr[$i].ChildNodes.Count - 1)].SetAttribute('class', 'normal')
    }
}

$body = "<h1>Server Status</h1>"
$body = $body + "<p>Below is the weekly usage report for Azure VMs from $st to $et.</p>"
$body = $body + $($HTMLBody.innerxml)


$convertToHtmlBody = ConvertTo-Html -Head $header -Body $body | Out-String
```

Comment: Do not compare as string, because `10` will be smaller than `2` (or `2` will be larger than `10`).   Do comparison on **numeric** values. (and, next time, provide a [mre]. That way you need less formatting to do, and the problem would be clearer, For example: https://onlinegdb.com/kUGrgkfov (when those `%` signs would not show, but they do!))

Comment: Right, I got the point. But if I compare with numeric values, I cannot append with "%" in the values so I have used string.

Comment: No, adding a `%` sign is a display thing, and you need to separate display stuff from your data.

Comment: @Luuk I tried this below logic which prints with '%'. It still doesn't recognize because the condition is only evaluating only int value but not with percent value. Is there a data type which evaluates percent ?


$memUsagePercent = (($totalMemInGB - $availableMemInGB) / $totalMemInGB).ToString('P')

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (So, I can copy/paste your code, and see the same thing as you have, only with my data....)

Comment: $memUsagePercent = (($totalMemInGB - $availableMemInGB) / $totalMemInGB).ToString('P')

Comment: I can't provide minimal reproducible example since this metric usage are from Azure VMs

Comment: Ok, sorry, I do not have more time to help you with this....

Answer (score 0):

- Indeed, `-gt` generally only performs *numerical* comparison if (at least) the  *LHS* is an actual *number*, which is by definition *not* the case for the text node values of an XML document.
- However, if you ensure that both string operands are formatted the same, with the exact same number of digits and decimal places (with static parts such as `.` and `%` being the same), the resulting *lexical* comparison is equivalent to numerical comparison.

Given that `$thresholdPercent` has a verbatim value of `75.00%`, you can format the table values the same, using the following technique:

```bash
# ...

# The raw numerical calculation of the ratio:
# No need to calculate a *percentage* here, and no need to *round*.
$memUsagePercent = ($totalMemInGB - $availableMemInGB) / $totalMemInGB

# ...

[PSCustomObject] @{
  # ...
  # Now convert the ratio to a string representation along the lines of
  # '75.00%' or '09.00%':
  MemoryUsagePercent = $memUsagePercent.ToString('P2').PadLeft(6, '0')
}
```

- `.ToString('P2')` formats a given ratio as a percent value rounded to 2 decimal places, suffixed with `%`, using the [standard `P` format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stand.ard-numeric-format-strings#percent-format-specifier-p)
- Since it appears that you cannot also specify the number of digits *before* the decimal point as part of the format string, [`.PadLeft(6, '0')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.PadLeft) is used to ensure that single-digit percent values are left-padded with a `0` (`6` is the desired number of characters *in total*, i.e. 2 significant digits, the `.`, the 2 decimal places, and the `%`).

Two simple examples:

```bash
# -> '50.09%'
(0.50086).ToString('P2').PadLeft(6, '0')

# -> '05.01%'
(0.05006).ToString('P2').PadLeft(6, '0')
```